# Looking for complex example of OPA code/rules

Tags: oracle-policy-automation

Can anyone point me to an example of a decent sized chunk of OPA code (i.e. a rule .docx)?  I'm having a terrible time Googling, as all I get are "This is why OPA is so great and what it can do" results with tiny snippets of code.  I've been told to figure out an OPA solution to an issue and have never used it before.  I've actually gotten pretty far but I keep running into little obstacles that I think a solid example of a complex rule with many conditions would really help me solve.

Comment: Are you not satisfied with their list of apps ? https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/wiki/Opa-Apps

Comment: That's Opa, it's a different framework.  I was asking about OPA (Oracle Policy Automation) for automating business rules.     I've gotten pretty far with it now, but would still like to see a large, complex rule project as I still run into occasional syntax issues that I cannot seem to solve using traditional research methods.

Comment: Ok. FYI I was linked here [by Opa home page](http://opalang.org/).